# Jenkins Pipeline hangs on node, yarn install

Tags: node.js, shell, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I try to build for one of my Laravel Project a simple pipeline script for continuous integration with Jenkins which involves couple of simple steps.

```
build
compile assets
test
deploy
```

the process works fine till is not starting to compile the assets, on assets compile to hole process hangs and is not getting executed to the end.

As background I'm using Centos 7 and for the assets compile node-10.0.0 and here is the jenkins pipeline snippet

```
node {

   stage('Install dependencies') {
      // Run Composer
      sh 'rm -rf vendor'
      sh 'composer install'
      //sh 'cp .env.example .env'
      sh 'php artisan key:generate'
   }

   stage('Compile Assets') {
       env.NODE_ENV = "test"
       print "Environment will be : ${env.NODE_ENV}"
       sh 'rm -rf node_modules'
       sh 'node -v'
       sh 'yarn install --ignore-engines'
   }

   stage('Run PHP Tests') {
       sh "vendor/bin/phpunit"
   }

}
```

[image: Pipeline]

[image]

Comment: Which pipeline do you use? Scripting or Delcrative?

Comment: I use scripting pipeline

Comment: ok we did declarative pipeline of jenkins

Comment: Dipak, how did you get Yarn working with declarative pipeline?